Airdump showing many BSSID for one router
As my title suggests, I have problem about airdump because I saw neighbor's wifi just showing 2.4ghz and 5ghz with one BSSID and ESSI (Thuan Ky), so for example, I sent image above, "Deco E4" and "Deco E4 5Ghz" are showing many different bssid, so I would try to run sudo aireplay-ng to try ddos but it's not working with many bssid, so do you guys know how to detect which is primary to try?


Be careful sharing wan BSSIDs, there are databases out there that link them to real addresses. (I wont leak it here for privacy reasons.)
